# Webpack Dev Server: Error occurred while proxying request [ECONNRESET]

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have a React app that uses webpack dev server for localhost. There's a proxy NodeJS server to which Webpack redirects all UI requests. When I run webpack dev server and open the app in Chrome, the page keeps refreshing continuously. On inspecting webpack dev server logs, I found that the connection is getting reset every second. It gives the following error:

`[webpack-dev-server] [HPM] Error occurred while proxying request localhost:3000 to http://[::1]:8081/ [ECONNRESET] (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)`

Here is my webpack.config:

```
{
  mode: 'development',
  devtool: 'source-map',
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      path: require.resolve('path-browserify'),
      react: require.resolve('react'),
      'react-dom': require.resolve('react-dom'),
      'react-router-dom': require.resolve('react-router-dom'),
      'spectra-ui-commons$': require.resolve('spectra-ui-commons')
    }
  },
  entry: {
    'app-shell': APP_PATH
  },
  output: {
    path: BUILD_PATH,
    filename: isDev ? '[name].js' : '[name].[hash].js',
    assetModuleFilename: 'assets/[name].[ext]'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
        include: `${APP_PATH}/apps`,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'ts-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
        type: 'asset/resource'
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: 'svg-sprite-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          'css-loader',
          'postcss-loader',
          'sass-loader'
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  devServer: {
    static: {
      directory: BUILD_PATH,
      staticOptions: {},
      watch: true,
      publicPath: '/build/app/'
    },
    devMiddleware: {
      writeToDisk: true
    },
    compress: true,
    open: true,
    hot: true,
    port: 3000,
    allowedHosts: 'all',
    proxy: {
      '/': 'http://[::1]:8081'
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExternalTemplateRemotesPlugin(),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: isDev ? '[name].css' : '[name].[hash].css',
      chunkFilename: isDev ? '[id].css' : '[id].[hash].css'
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.env': JSON.stringify(process.env.env || 'development'),
      'env.backendHost': JSON.stringify('http://localhost:8081')
    })
  ]
};
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Your fix the error?